# Options for saying, "my number is"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, usage, sentence-structure

I'm currently writing a formal-ish e-mail in which I need to give someone my phone number. My first instinct is to simply write:

> Meine Nummer, die Sie die SMS senden können, ist _________.

However... saying ***Meine Nummer ist ______*** sounds very "English" or informal to me. I have the feeling that there's a more "German" way to say that. Can anyone give me different options to express this? Am I missing some element to make this more grammatically correct?

Here are some I've considered but I'm not sure if they're correct:

> Meine Nummer, die Sie die SMS senden können, steht an _________.
>
> Meine Nummer, die Sie die SMS senden können, geht an ________.
>
> Meine Nummer, die Sie die SMS an schicken können, geht an ________.

Comment: None is, unfortunately, the relative clause is not correct (also you could try something like *gerne per SMS*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Meine Nummer ist* is indeed used quite often in German and not an "English" term at all.

So if you would like to stick with your relative clause construct, it would be

> Meine Nummer, **an** die Sie die SMS senden können, ist die _______.

But this reads a little bit "holprig" (rough).

I personally would rather go with a much simpler approach like:

> Sie können mich gerne unter der Nummer _______ per SMS kontaktieren.

or

> Sie erreichen mich per SMS unter der Nummer _______.

That is all: polite, formal and it reads quite natural.

Answer (score 4):

The question I have with your question is: do you want to write that in a sentence or just as information? If you just want to give your number as information you can just write:

> Telefonnummer: *YourNumber*

No sentence.
But if you more or less need to write a whole sentence, you can write this:

> Gerne können Sie mir eine SMS an folgende Telefonnummer senden: *YourNumber*.

or this:

> Wenn Sie mir eine SMS senden möchten, bitte ich Sie, diese an die folgende Telefonnummer zu schicken: *YourNumber*.

Comment: I don't know whether this is a southern German thing, but "senden" for email, SMS, or letter seems pretty rare (and a bit English)  "Schicken" seems universal.

Answer (score 1):

To pack all information in a short manner:

> - [Meine] Telefonnummer (auch für SMS): *0123 4567890*
> - [Meine] Telefon-Nr. (auch für SMS): *0123 4567890*
> - [Meine] Tel.-Nr. (auch für SMS): *0123 4567890*
> - Telefon (auch für SMS): *0123 4567890*
> - Fon (auch für SMS): *0123 4567890*

Additionally you can replace *»für«* by the well known abbreviation *»f.«*.

Comment: How can the listener differentiate whether the number is fo a cell phone or an old fashioned phone? The people say also meine Handynummer is bla bla bla. You may add also this.

Comment: If he explicitely adds "auch für SMS", then it is very likely the number of a cell phone.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: I don't think it's a problem since _»(auch für SMS)«_ is added.

Comment: I did not think that the part in the paranthesis will be said loudly.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Why *should* the listener be concerned wether the number is a fixed line or cell phone number?  SMS is in many countries also available on fixed phone lines. Specifying that the number can receive text messages does not necessarily mean that it is a cell phone number, but why is the distinction relevant at all in the context of this question?

Comment: @jarnbjo I did not say it especially for this context. However, generally it is always to know whether the number, which I am calling, is a cell phone or not. Because, in case of a cell phone, the accessibility is anyhow better.

Comment: In Germany you can normally tell cell phone numbers from fixed lines as all cell phone numbers start with 015, 016 or 017 whereas no fixed number starts with these prefixes, as you can read [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorwahl_01_(Deutschland))

Comment: @TorstenLink Very good tip. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AdInfinitum Contactability is very person specific.  For contacting my partner, the house phone number is much more reliable than her Handy.  She will hear the house phone; her Handy is quite likely to be off, or just not heard in her handbag.

Comment: @TorstenLink: the odds are high that TBR doesn't have a German mobile number!

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, you are absolutely right...